# Angular JS - controller doesn't work when ngRoute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an application using HTML, CSS and AngularJS under Ionic and I'm having troubles about routing.

My problem is that the dependancy "ngRoute" in my index.js makes my controller not working.

Here is my html filer (index.html) :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="medathle" ng-controller="ModalCtrl">

    <!-- MedAthle logo -->
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo_medathle.png">
    </div>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div class="index-btn">
        <button class="button button-block button-large button-balanced" ng-click="openLogin()">
        Se connecter
        </button>
        <button class="button button-block button-large button-balanced" href="#!menu">
        En savoir plus
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Login Modal -->
    <script id="login.html" type="text/ng-template">

      <div class="modal">

        <!-- Modal header bar -->
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
          <h1 class="title">Se connecter</h1>
          <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="closeLogin()">Annuler</button>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <!-- Modal content area -->
        <ion-content>

          <form>
            <div class="login-input">
                <div class="email-block">
                    <label for id="email">
                        Adresse email
                        <input class="item-input-wrapper" type="email" id="email">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdp-block">
                    <label for id="mdp">
                        Mot de passe
                        <input class="item-input-wrapper" type="password" id="mdp">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="login-btn">
                <button type="submit" href="#/menu" class="button button-large button-outline button-balanced">Connexion</button>
            </div>
          </form>

        </ion-content>
      </div>

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my js file (index.js) :

```
angular.module('medathle', ['ionic', 'ngRoute'])


.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) { 

        // Système de routage
        $routeProvider
        .when('/menu', {
            templateUrl: 'menu.html',
            controller: 'ModalCtrl'
        });
    }
]);

.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

    // Create and load the Modal
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('login.html', function(modal) {
      $scope.loginModal = modal;
    }, {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });

    // Called when the form is submitted


    // Open our new task modal
    $scope.openLogin = function() {
      $scope.loginModal.show();
    };

    // Close the new task modal
    $scope.closeLogin = function() {
      $scope.loginModal.hide();
    };
  })

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })
```

If I delete 'ngRoute' in my module (index.js file), then it's working. But I don't understand why just a few words can have a such impact on my controller ?

If you can help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

ngRoute got deprecated. Now you have to use Angular "ui-route" for routing in Angular 1. The code below may be helpful for you.

```
**First install angular-ui-router package 
--via npm: by running $ npm install angular-ui-router from your console
   or
-- via Bower: by running $ bower install angular-ui-router from your console**

**add path of package angular-ui-router path in index file in script tag.**

then use below code in you app module according to your requirement.

**angular.module("angular1App", ["ui.router"])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("category");
    $stateProvider
      .state("login", {
        url: "/main",
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl",
      })
      .state("register", {
        url: "/register",
        templateUrl: "views/register.html",
        controller: "RegisteryCtrl",
      });
  })**
```

For more information visit the link below:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router